# How to perform a transformation to each slice individually?

Tags: vtk, itk

I have a series of Xray images of a cylindrical part. With that, I can create 
and visualize the volume, but the data appear like a stack of slices from -Z 
to Z which is expected. 
What I want is to **rotate each slice image with an incremental angle along 
Y-axis** to make the whole volume cylindrical. Something like the following 
c++ code.

I have tried **vtkImageReslice** but it transforms the whole volume data not 
each slice in an incremental way. How can I perform this kind of transformation to each slice individually? Any solution in VTK or in ITK?

Thanks,

```
void RotateEachSliceImage(VtkSliceImages& images) 
{ 
        int countImages = images.size(); 

        double incrementalAngle = 360.0 / countImages;  // incremental angle for 
each image 

        double angle = incrementalAngle; 

        for (int i = 1; i < countImages; i++) 
        { 
                images[i].rotate(angle, 1); // along Y axis 

                angle = angle + incrementalAngle; 
        } 
} 

int main() 
{ 
        VtkSliceImages slices(2400); 
        RotateEachSliceImage(slices); 
        RenderToVtk(slices); 

        return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to resample a volume slice by slice. Instead of using reslice mapper, try using resample filter e.g. [ITK's ResampleImageFilter](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1ResampleImageFilter.html).

Comment: I have already played with this filter but couldn't get any result. Can you please point me to the right example or any sample code?

Comment: Example which demonstrates usage: https://itk.org/ITKExamples/src/Filtering/ImageGrid/ResampleAnImage/Documentation.html